# Displaying JSON data in Tabular format using R

Tags: r, json

I currently want to use Rstudio extract the JSON data and display it in a neat tabular format.This is the JSON Data I am currently using:

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "company": {
    "carid": "23456",
    "companyCode": "T.FX05",
    "companyName": "Toyota",
    "companyMethodology": {
      "$id": "34567",
      "meth": null
    },
    "Midnightshift": 0,
    "cars": [
      {
        "carid": "78910",
        "carcode": "T.FX07",
        "cardetails": {
          "carid": "45678",
          "cardetailscode": "T.MPV",
          "carname": "camry",
        },
        "specialisedcarCode": null
      },
      {
        "carid": "67892",
        "code": "T.FX08",
        "cardetails": {
          "carid": "89546",
          "cardetailscode": "T.CEA",
          "carname": "celica",
        },
        "specialisedcarCode": null
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am currently using the following code:

```
#install.packages("rjson")

library("rjson")


json_file <- "http:xxxx"

json_data <- fromJSON(file=json_file)
json_data_car <- json_data$company$cars

finalTable_car <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, json_data_car))
```

The above code allows me to extract the data and display tables of 'Company' and 'Cardetails'. However, I am getting errors when I try to extract the data further and  display the data of 'cardetails'.

```
json_data_car <- json_data$company$cars$cardetails
```

> The error I am getting is: Error in do.call(rbind, json_data_car) :
>   second argument must be a list

Any ideas how to go about it and display all the data in a table format?

Comment: The `jsonlite` package and it's corresponding code - `jsonlite::fromJSON(json_file)` seems to cope with this a lot better. Though you do have to fix the trailing commas in the original json like `"carname": "camry",` which seem to not be valid json according to `jsonlite`

Comment: looks like your json file has incomplete list, please check the format of json

Comment: @thelatemail I cannot fix up the JSON file. I am reading it off a webservice. Any ideas how to go about this now?